# Сжатие изображения

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5

Приветствую. Нужна опять ваша помощь.

Я делаю ресайз изображения через HTML5 canvas при загрузке:

```
ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Потом получаю его, указывая качество:
     canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg",0.01);

Но на выходе у меня изображение не теряет в качестве, а вес его еще и больше исходного, хотя и указываю минимальное 0,01. Не могу понять, почему так получается.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

см. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

> A Number between 0 and 1 indicating image quality if the requested type is **image/jpeg** or **image/webp**.
>   If this argument is anything else, the default value for image quality is used. Other arguments are ignored.

Попробуйте

```
.toDataURL("image/**jpeg**", 0.01);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: ок! + 12 буквок